# What does very much sweating mean?

Tags: sweat

Every time I do sports, I sweat really much - no matter whether I play soccer or do some bodyweight exercises. My fitness level is quite good and I don't get out of breath that easyly, but still I am sweating very much every time. What could be the reason for this? Does it mean that I am not as fit as I think I am? Other people, who don't have a fitness level like me don't seem to sweat very much. I am a little confused about what all that means. Should I have my heart circulation system checked or something like that?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything - some people sweat lots, some people don't. Make sure you stay well hydrated, but other than that don't worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not always it means something. While your body is quite responsive and flushes out waste quite frequently, it also loses water and electrolytes. Make sure you hydrate yourself properly and regularly. If you have every seen Brock Lesnar workout, that guy loses around half a gallon to a gallon of workout during one session, but have we ever seen a fighter like him? Whether in the octagon, or in the ring, I have never seen a man close to 300lbs in weight move so swiftly. So, don't worry, you just need to keep yourself hydrated and the salt levels in your body maintained.